# Create a string that lists the amount of object types in a queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a string that prints out the totals of each type of item in a queryset for the following model.

```
class Booking(models.Model):

    _JACKET_SIZES = (
        ('s', 'Small'),
        ('m', 'Medium'),
        ('l', 'Large'),
        ('xl', 'X Large'),
        ('xxl', '2X Large'),
        ('unknown', 'Unsure'),
    )

    ...
    jacket_size = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=_JACKET_SIZES, default='small', null=True)
    ...
```

Basically, I'm trying to collate a list of jacket sizes into a string. This is what I have attempted already but I am sure there is an easier way.

```
bookings = Booking.objects.all()

jackets = {}
for booking in bookings:
    jackets.setdefault(booking.get_jacket_size_display(), jackets.get(booking_get_jacket_size_display(), 0) + 1)

o = ', '.join('{}: {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in jackets.items()])
```

Lets assume that the queryset contains 4 objects. 1 Small jacket, 2 medium jackets and 1 large jacket.

The result of the above code only seems to provide 1 Medium, not 2 as if it was ignoring the second medium jacket.

Comment: Please share the (relevant parts of the) models.

Comment: I've updated the post for the model

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by performing an `.annotate(..)`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Booking.objects.values('jacket_size').annotate(
    number=Count('id')
).order_by('jacket_size')
```

This will give a `QuerySet` that contains dictionaries like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'jacket_size': 'l', 'number': 12},
    {'jacket_size': 'm', 'number': 25},
    {'jacket_size': 's', 'number': 31},
    {'jacket_size': 'unknown', 'number': 17},
    {'jacket_size': 'xl', 'number': 9},
    {'jacket_size': 'xxl', 'number': 7},
]>
```

Some remarks:

1. `jacket_size`s for which there is no `Booking`, will *not* show up in the database, since the database does not know these sizes exist, and thus you might want to "patch" the data (by converting it to a list or dictionary, and adding missing entries);
2. the `.order_by(..)` is necessary to force a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Great, however, is there a way to make it use the display (like get_FOO_display() would do) rather than the key name?

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman: no, but you can iterate over the options and "replace" these. The reason this is not possible is because the database does not know anything about the display counterpart. It only sees the values, not the "Python logic" related to it.